# What is the difference between Sarga and Pratisarga?

Tags: puranas

In Puranas Sarga and Pratisarga are described. Sarga means creation. Then what is Pratisarga? Vivek Debroy wrote in the introduction of Vishnu Purana that within a creation there are secondary creations, which are known as Pratisarga. I do not understand what it means.

Comment: Sarga occurs only once in the lifespan of Brahma(ie the new Brahmas first day)  soon after His Birth , So Sarga follows Prakrutha Pralaya.. thenceforth it is only through Pratisarga ,Brahma creates beings when His new Day(kalpa) dawns (soon after naimittika Pralaya).Mahat , ahamkara, tanmatras , indriyas and their presiding deities are part of sarga. . plants animals humans celestial creation are part of Pratisarga.Concisely, samshti srshti is Sarga ,but then vyashti shrshti is Pratisarga